# decltype confusing is there any need

Tags: c++, decltype

// In which case the first pice of code will fail and 
// I need to switch to second piece of  code

```
 template<typename A, typename B>     // 1
 auto add(A const& a, B const& b) { return a + b; }

 template<typename A, typename B>     // 2
 auto add(A const& a, B const& b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first way didnt work before c++14, introducing return type deduction.  That is when you need the second form.

Comment: The second is also SFINAE-friendly

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Would you mind to give some explanations? Why the first one is not SFINAE-friendly?

Comment: @songyuanyao the expression in a trailing return type serves as an expression SFINAE; if it's ill-formed, the overload is excluded from the set of candidates. this does not hold for `auto` return type deduction (the expression in a return statement is not inspected during overload resolution)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks!